# How to do regularization in Matlab's NN toolbox

Tags: matlab, neural-network, deep-learning, regression, prediction

My data set has 150 independent variables and 10 predictors or response. The problem is to find a mapping between input and output variables. There are 1000 data points out of which 70% I have used for training and 30% for testing. I am using a feedforward neural network with 10 hidden neurons as explained in this [Matlab document](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/trainlm.html) . I am evaluating the performance using the command

```
perf_Train = perform(net,TrainedData',lblTrain')

YPred = net(XTest);
perf_Test = perform(net,YPred,lblTest')
```

which basically gives the mean square error between the actual and the predicted (estimated) response for training and testing. My testing data is not able to fit properly to the trained model, however the training data fits quite well.

**Problem1**: My training performance is always lesser than test performance measure i.e., `perf_Train = 0.0867` and `perf_Test = 0.567`

Is this overfitting or underfitting?

**Problem2**: How do I make the test data fit accurately? Theory say that to overcome overfitting and underfitting, we need to do regularization. Is there any parameter that needs to be input into the function such as regularization to overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is overfitting since training error is lower than test error. 
I would recommend to set less epochs(iteration) for your training or use less training data.
I would also recommend to check that the training data and test data are picked up randomly.

For regulation, it can be set like this:

```
net.performParam.regularization = 0.5;
```

The performance ratio depends on the model, 0.5 is just an example.

For more details, you can refer to the documentation below.
https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ug/improve-neural-network-generalization-and-avoid-overfitting.html#bss4gz0-38

Comment: Thank you for the information and the link to the document. I have few comments, could you please clarify? (1) When the dataset is  split into train, validation and test set,  usually over or underfitting is reported based on validation set. But, I was unable to find out overfitting or underfitting since Matlab  automatically splits the train into train and validation. Therefore, is it legitimate to report overfitting or underfitting based on the unseen test data?

Comment: (2) I think if  validation error > training error, we have overfitting case. In my case, test error > training error, so does the concept of overfitting apply to the test error set as well? (you mentioned it as underfitting instead or overfitting, kindly check).

Comment: Sorry you are right, the perform function gives the error, i thought it was the inverse. So as you wrote, it is overfitting in your case.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification and correction. In most books and tutorials it is suggested to apply 70% of the data for training and the rest 30% as unseen for testing. But why do you suggest to use less training data and how much to use then? Can you please explain a bit? Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: Generally speaking 70% is good, but there is no rule about that. You have to try to find the best combination. You may check your training data, if there are lot of similar data, you will artificially have good performance.